# flex itemRenderer variables from/to main scope

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, scope, actionscript-2, itemrenderer

I'm working on creating a datagrid that has a checkbox column. I have some functions that run within the itemRenderer that creates an array collection containing the item information and weather or not the checkbox is checked or not.

Everything seems to be work the way I'd like, but now I just need to access the arraycollection created in the itemRenderer scope in my main application. How can I go about access this?

Here's the function that creates the AC within the itemRenderer

```
private function onChange():void {
      data["isSelected"] = cb.selected;
        var dp:ArrayCollection = _dataGrid.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
        dp.dispatchEvent(new CollectionEvent(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE));               
    }
```

Comment: Let the parent of the Datagrid (or the datagrid itself) listen for the event and then dispatch an event against the display list or event bus (if you have an event bus). However, this may not be the best approach for your situation. If you'd like to offer more details, perhaps someone could offer a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second the approach letting a dedicated event bubble through the DataGrid towards the controller. This lets you create loosely coupled components and is easy to implement as well.